# Add Video in sidebar layout wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress,I am using interface theme (http://themehorse.com/preview/interface/) ,I have downloaded a youtube video in mp4 format and uploaded it through Admin.Now i want to show this video in Widget Tab Business Page Section.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. It _might_ have a place on [WordPress.SE]; read their Help Center before asking there, and check if it hasn't been asked there already.

Answer (score 0):

Goto your widgets and drag the text widget to your desired sidebar. Then inside your widget type this code in

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="http://yoursite.com/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Replace the source link to yours and adjust the dimensions.